# fdisk output: "new DOS disklabel"

Tags: partition, fdisk, gpt, mbr

I have a question about what is happening here. Does "a new DOS disklabel" here mean a DOS partition table has been created? In other words, that a DOS partition table has been created by default, which then is deleted when option "g" creates a GPT partition table?

```
primus@ubu2104:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdd

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xb23a7979.

Command (m for help): g
Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: 4F2417FA-CE86-4649-A719-F47191C0742E).

Command (m for help):
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `fdisk` by default creates a “DOS” partition table, in memory. Creating a GPT partition table with `g` replaces that. If you actually write the first partition table before creating a GPT partition table, `fdisk` will explicitly tell you that’s it’s replacing the partition table:

> The old dos signature will be removed by a write command.

You can avoid this by starting `fdisk` with support for GPT only:

```
fdisk -t gpt /dev/sdd
```

You still need to type `g` to create a GPT partition table.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is written to the disk until you tell `fdisk` to (with the `w` command) so the DOS partition table wasn't actually written to the disk. But because the disk doesn't have partition table, `fdisk` automatically scheduled creation of one. This is just a helper function so you don't have to do that manually and you can create partition (with `n`) without thinking about the partition table. If you decide to create the GPT partition table (with `g`), the scheduled creation of the DOS partition table is canceled and only the GPT partition table will be created.

You can avoid the automatic partition table creation with `-n`/`--noauto-pt`.

Comment: Nice, I didn’t know about `-n`! I see it was added in util-linux 2.36.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a protective partition which covers the whole disk and made to be sure GPT un-compatible partition handling will not consider the disk empty.

The actual partitions are the GPT partitions (included in the whole « DOS » partition).

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#/ and its protective MBR at sector 0.

Comment: No, this is different; the default DOS partition table created by `fdisk` before the user does anything is empty. The protective partition is only created if a GPT partition table is created. You can see the difference by running `fdisk -t dos -l /path/to/device`.